# How can I use Variable expressions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In PHP I can use a double dollar sign to use a variable to represent another variable. If like to do the same in AngularJS expressions.

For example if I had an object with `property1`, `property2` etc each with different values I would reference them directly as `{{$scope.property1}}`

What I would like to do is something like `string propertyToDisplay = 'property1'` and then use `{{$scope.propertyToDisplay}}` show the value stored in `property1`.

Does AngularJS support this?

Comment: Do you have a more specific use case, respecively what do you really want to achieve?

Comment: BTW in the views u shouldn't access `property1` like u stated, the right way is `{{property1}}`

Comment: I plan to get a result from a query which will be returned as an object. And I want to all the user to choose which fields are displayed. The user will define both the query and the fields they want the form to display. Hope that use case is helpful

Comment: In general, there isn't a way to access a variable via a string that holds its name. (unless you use `eval()`, but `eval()` is evil). You _can_ access a property of an object using a string. And that does indeed appear to be what you are looking to do here, but it seems like you're going about problem the wrong way. Generally, the `$scope` variable shouldn't be appearing in your view templates at all.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking the time to provide examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  In general, the `$scope` variable shouldn't be appearing in your views at all, let alone that you seem to be trying to go outside the boundaries of what should be put in the markup for an AngularJS view.

In general, the parts of your controller that should appear in your view are (1) properties of the scope (or properties of properties, etc.) (2) functions that are part of the scope (with scope properties passed in as arguments). For anything involving dynamic functionality, you should generally be using the latter. So you could have your controller defined like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.properties = {
        property1: "Hey!",
        property2: "Hi"
    };

    $scope.selectedProperty = '';

    $scope.getProperty = function (propertyName) {
        return $scope.properties[propertyName];
    };
}]);
```

And then your view could have something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedProperty">
   <option value="property1">Property 1</option>
   <option value="property2">Property 2</option>
</select>
<p>The value of the property you selected is: {{getProperty(selectedProperty)}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access variable object attribute using square brackets:

`attrname ='attribute_name';`

`obj[attrname] = something;`

Comment: So if I had something like $scope.resultObject that had the object how should the syntax look?

Comment: @JosephU. You can access it as `$scope['resultObject']` or if you had the property name in a variable `propName`, you could use `$scope[propName]`. Just a friendly bit of advice, but you seem to be trying to use AngularJS without having grasped the basics of JavaScript, let alone the established practices for using AngularJS. Perhaps some tutorials are in order?

Answer (score 0):

How about using another object to store the visibility of each object property ([**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fAS5PRJHIkGmHxj0OXI2?p=preview)).

```
$scope.visible = {};

$scope.person = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Rambo',
    city: 'Hollywood'
};
```

Create a list with checkboxes for each property:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in person">
  <input id="{{key}}Check" type="checkbox" ng-model="visible[key]">
  <label for="{{key}}Check">{{key}}</label>
</div>
```

And check the visibility of each property in the form:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.first_name" ng-show="visible['first_name']">
```

If you want the form to be dynamic too (only input fields in this case) you can of course put this in a ng-repeat too:

```
<input ng-repeat="(key, value) in person" type="text" ng-model="person[key]" ng-show="visible[key]">
```

Hope this is at least close to what you want.